# regular expression to all fields accept some html tags in yii pattern validation rule

Tags: html, validation, yii

I am using yii validation rules for remove all special characters from input field.

But i want to add some html tags to add by users in input field.

So i use following code ...

```
array('product_name, product_description', 'match', 'pattern'=>"/^['<br/> \"0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]*$/i")
```

In above code i just added `<br/>`  html tag to allow it in validation rule.

But yii pattern not allowing me to input it in input field.

may i doing wrong something.

So how do i allow some html tags to allow user add in input field.

Answer (score 1):

Match Validator just checks whether your field matches the pattern or not.

For your goals you should write custom validator or validation rule.
In its simplest form it can look like (yii2 version example, but it uses native php function so it can be moved to version 1):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['product_name', 'product_description'], function($value) {
            return strip_tags($value, '<br>');
        }],

    ];
}
```

To clarify how to specify allowed tags look at manual for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)

To clarify how to write custom validation rule for yii1.1, please also check a [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/)

Comment: Thank for your quick answer. Can i add allow tags in yii pattern ...?

Comment: @satyawan IMHO You can use match only for one reason - check existence of tags in string that you DONT allow (because if you check tags that you allow it does not mean that the string does not contain forbidden tags). But this list can be too long for this case.